# How can I resize an image so it fits the entire window?

Tags: html, image, css

I have an image for a website and I wish to resize it so it covers ANY given screen.

Note:

- I don't want the scrollbars to appear.
- I am trying to resemble something like the following website

  http://frontrow-demo.squarespace.com/

The only solution I can think of was re-sizing the height and width but that makes the scroll bars appear.  I am guessing its a CSS solution I am struggling to create.

Edit:

This is the code I tried, but its "Zooming" the pic to make it stretch across the screen. I would like it to resize it so the quality and the actual pic would show up.

```
#bg {
  position: fixed; 
  top: 0; 
  left: 0; 

  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Do you have *any* code?  "I tried some stuff and it didn't work" is not helpful.

Comment: have you seen what happens when you make the supplied website smaller (horizontally)? It seems to be mobile friendly.

Comment: You would like to make the image bigger but not lose quality? I do not think this is possible unless you took the picture with a nice camera.

Comment: @LoganMurphy I think the pic is quality, this is the pic I am trying to use to play around with.. http://chromatology.files.wordpress.com/2013/05/24.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use the CSS background property: http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

```
html { 
  background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Works in:

Safari 3+
Chrome Whatever+
IE 9+
Opera 10+ (Opera 9.5 supported background-size but not the keywords)
Firefox 3.6+ (Firefox 4 supports non-vendor prefixed version)

Comment: Please don't only post links, include the code, links can die over time.

Comment: Yeah, this article will give him plenty of choices to choose the one that's right for him. :)

Comment: @AdamS - You're right, but I don't think this article is going anywhere. And there's quite a bit to choose from in it, pros and cons, what browsers each method works in, etc.

Comment: hey tim, great site. I tried the first example but it didnt work, the technique #2 worked but its not resizing the pic, its "zooming" it to make it stretch across the window.

Comment: @Umz15 unfortunately you're going to have issues like that unless you use a really big image. You're taking an image that is one dimension, and making it fit a browser window which will be another dimension. What didn't work in the first example? What browser are you using? Try CSS-Only Technique #2 and see if that works for you.

Comment: I am using chrome, I think I have to resize the image myself beforehand and then try it. But hey, great website - added to favourite ;)

Comment: That should work in chrome. make sure you're using a large enough image :)

Answer (score 3):

Just use some simple css

```
#theimg {
    position : fixed; /*can also use absolute and the parent element can have relative*/
    top : 0;
    left : 0;
    width : 100%;
    height : 100%;
}
```

here is a demo fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/rg3eK/

Comment: @insertusernamehere can't avoid image distortion if you stretch it...just need a really big image that is proportionally appealing...unfortunately my demo uses a bad image

Comment: You could use `height:auto`, but that defeated the purpose of it stretching.

Comment: But you never know how the aspect ratio of the viewport is. In the link in the OP the image always keeps its aspect ratio.

Comment: @insertusernamehere You have a valid point but The OP wants a method that makes an image that "covers ANY given screen".

Answer (score 2):

Anchor it to the sides and set the size to `auto`.

```
img#fullscreen {
    height:auto;
    width:100%;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    top:0;
    position:absolute;
}
```

[Working fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/6brCu/3)

This won't resize to the bottom (the one on the linked page also doesn't) but also doesn't mess the aspect of the image.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check [photo-resize](https://github.com/gutierrezalex/photo-resize) option.

Or you may try adding this:-

```
<img src="picture.jpg" width="100%" alt="">
```

**ie, if you set only one dimension of an image, the other will end up being proportional to it.**

or this:-

```
#image{
min-width:100%;
min-height:100%;
height:auto;
width:auto;
left:0;
right:0;
bottom:0;
top:0;}
```

Comment: OP said nothing about using jQuery for this.

Comment: @Boaz: That is why I have added the second option ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use `background-size: cover` in **CSS** on the `HTML` element

```css
html {
    background: url(http://i.imgur.com/tENv1w4.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
       -moz-background-size: cover;
         -o-background-size: cover;
            background-size: cover;
}
```

See this fiddle:

## [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/n5qfa)

Comment: i've tried this method, it didnt work for me, the pic didnt show up

Comment: Does this fiddle work when you click on it?  If so there might be something in your code causing the issue.  Can you reproduce it in a fiddle of your own?

Answer (score 0):

For a better css.you must use this

```
html { 
  background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```